# What is the concept of "shopping cart"?

Tags: shopping-cart

I would like to ask what is the concept of "shopping cart"? Record item and do the calculation? If I want to write such a program, which approach should I take: using client side language or server side language? I think it would secure if I use server side language, but how can I store the information other than using cookie and store the data in client's hard disk?

Comment: If you are going to implement a shopping cart, take that extra step and spend (atleast) about 30 bucks on an SSL certificate. It'll give you a little extra security, and will help your visitors trust you more.

Comment: Also, there are other things to consider. There are websites (and even software) that scan cookies and saves browser data and upload this information to their servers. I'm sure many people would object to companies knowing what they're purchasing online. I would not use client-side cookies; use Session cookies if you must, and store information in a database.

Answer (score 0):

if you don t want use cookie you need to feed your database table "cart" with the id product, the quantity, the price, and the user id
of course this work only if the user is logged, it s why prefer use cookie for unlogged users